# How are class, package, document writers using modifications to \catcode

Tags: catcodes

I'm thinking that the primary uses of changing `\catcode` in LaTeX are to:

- enable “private” macros (e.g., `\makeatletter` ... `\@foo` ... `\makeatother` or the expl3 syntax
- allow for verbatim-like commands/environments

Is there any widespread use of active characters beyond `~`?

(Note: I'm not asking about the meanings of the `\catcode`s as set up by TeX/LaTeX, but the cases where they get changed from those defaults.)

Comment: `babel` makes quite a few characters active to allow language shorthands, for example

Comment: The `underscore` package makes `_` active, with all sorts of weird effects.

Comment: | is often set a "short verb"  char.

Comment: For legacy engines, the entire inputenc system is based on making most "characters" active.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as well as `"` for "short verb*" (less frequently used).

Comment: `xii.tex` makes many characters active, which brings us to the core of using `\catcode` too much: It's used for obfuscating and code golfing.

Comment: Some packages use different category codes of the same token to create unlikely input-delimiters or flags. An example would be the `-NoValue-` marker used in `xparse`, in which the first `-` is of category 11 and the second `-` 12.

Comment: Just reread my comment and realised there is a stupid mistake: It should be "of the same character", obviously, if they differ in category they aren't the same token!

Comment: I made `q` an escape character (like \ ) for helping with balanced touch-typing of court transcripts. Luckily, no kernel commands contain q! The inspiration was the `unisugar` package, which makes the 'interesting view' icon a command character for bidi purposes. Very handy.